Ckeditor5 - Copy and paste from Office (Word) does not work for lists
I am trying to implement Ckeditor5 in my website and I want to allwos the user to copy and paste from word, but the lists do not fully work.
When I copy this
1.Dfgdfgdfg
  Dfgdfgdfgdf
2.Dfgdfgdfg kjdfhgjdfhghdfhjg
  Dfgjhdfjhgjdhfghkjdhfghdfjg  dfjjhg dfjgh dfjhj gh dfhdgf
3.Dfgdfgjhdfj 
4.Dfgdfgdf
5.Dfgdfgdfg
6.Dfgdfgdf

I get this
1.Dfgdfgdfg
Dfgdfgdfgdf
2.Dfgdfgdfg kjdfhgjdfhghdfhjg
Dfgjhdfjhgjdhfghkjdhfghdfjg  dfjjhg dfjgh dfjhj gh dfhdgf hjdgf  
3.Dfgdfgjhdfj 
4.Dfgdfgdf
5.Dfgdfgdfg
6.Dfgdfgdf

I am trying this
`
DecoupledEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
        // Editor configuration.
        link: {
            addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
            defaultProtocol: 'https://',
            allowedProtocols: [ 'https'],
            decorators: {
                addTargetToExternalLinks: {
                    mode: 'automatic',
                    callback: url => /^(https?:)?\/\//.test( url ),
                    attributes: {
                        target: '_blank',
                        rel: 'noopener noreferrer'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        window.editor = editor;
        // Set a custom container for the toolbar.
        document.querySelector( '.document-editor__toolbar' ).appendChild( editor.ui.view.toolbar.element );
        document.querySelector( '.ck-toolbar' ).classList.add( 'ck-reset_all' );

        // Assuming editor is already initialized
        editor.editing.view.document.on('clipboardInput', (evt, data) => {
            const htmlData = data.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            if (htmlData) {
                // Manipulate the HTML structure to properly integrate text into lists
                const processedHtml = integrateTextIntoLists(htmlData);
                const viewFragment = editor.data.htmlProcessor.toView(processedHtml);
                const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
        
                // Insert the transformed content
                editor.model.change(writer => {
                    editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment, editor.model.document.selection);
                });
        
                // Stop the default processing to use our custom transformation
                evt.stop();
            }
        });
    } )
    .catch( handleSampleError );


function handleSampleError( error ) {
    const issueUrl = 'https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues';

    const message = [
        'Oops, something went wrong!',
        `Please, report the following error on ${ issueUrl } with the build id "m7gmbfwakd12-rztuvf3ew3ra" and the error stack trace:`
    ].join( '\n' );

    console.error( message );
    console.error( error );
}


function integrateTextIntoLists(html) {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    // Handle incorrect list item integration
    const lists = doc.querySelectorAll('ol, ul');
    lists.forEach(list => {
        let lastLi = list.lastElementChild; // Track the last <li> element

        // This is the node immediately following the current list
        let followingNode = list.nextSibling;
        while (followingNode) {
            const nextFollowingNode = followingNode.nextSibling;
            if (followingNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (followingNode.tagName === 'P' || followingNode.tagName === 'SPAN')) {
                // Move the node inside the last <li> if it's a <p> or <span>
                if (lastLi) {
                    lastLi.appendChild(followingNode);
                } else {
                    // If no <li> exists, create one
                    lastLi = document.createElement('li');
                    lastLi.appendChild(followingNode);
                    list.appendChild(lastLi);
                }
            } else {
                break; // Stop if the next node is not a <p> or <span>
            }
            followingNode = nextFollowingNode;
        }
    });

    return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
}


`
but it does not work, I am not using the paid version atm as the only thing that I need is to be able to copy and paste using bulled list or numbered lists

function integrateTextIntoLists(html) {
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

// Handle incorrect list item integration
const lists = doc.querySelectorAll('ol, ul');
lists.forEach(list => {
    let lastLi = list.lastElementChild; // Track the last <li> element

    // This is the node immediately following the current list
    let followingNode = list.nextSibling;
    while (followingNode) {
        const nextFollowingNode = followingNode.nextSibling;
        if (followingNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && 
   (followingNode.tagName === 'P' || followingNode.tagName === 'SPAN')) {
            // Move the node inside the last <li> if it's a <p> or <span>
            if (lastLi) {
                lastLi.appendChild(followingNode);
            } else {
                // If no <li> exists, create one
                lastLi = document.createElement('li');
                lastLi.appendChild(followingNode);
                list.appendChild(lastLi);
            }
        } else {
            break; // Stop if the next node is not a <p> or <span>
        }
        followingNode = nextFollowingNode;
    }
});

  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
}


Hi Hema, that does not work. It prints this 1.       DfgdfgdfgDfgdfgdfgdf2.       Dfgdfgdfg kjdfhgjdfhghdfhjgDfgjhdfjhgjdhfghkjdhfghdfjg  dfjjhg dfjgh dfjhj gh dfhdgf hjdgf hjdgfhjdgfhj dgfhj dgfdgfhjdfghjdfjh gdhfjg dfg3.       Dfgdfgjhdfj4.       Dfgdfgdf5.       Dfgdfgdfg6.       Dfgdfgdf.....
